# Bathroom door sticking

Tags: door-frame

Having the problem with my bathroom door downstairs sticking towards the bottom Thought I’d remove the bottom door hinge that’s screwed onto the door frame.  As you can see from the picture, there is a gap at the top but the bottom is tight. Because of this I couldn’t do the YouTube video suggestion of “bending” the hinges that is attached to the door.  Any inputs appreciated. [image]

Comment: First step would be to tighten the screws, followed by replacing them with a 1/4 inch longer screws.

Comment: Where is it sticking/binding on?  Right now the door stop seems not adjusted right.  They are usually just attached to the frame with small nails.  Usually with bottom not closing right, you adjust the top hinge by tightening the screws.  More pictures showing the hinges and where the door sticks will help.

Comment: Yeah, just how loose are your top hinges that the door is hanging 1/4" off the jamb? And I usually put long (like, 3") screws in the jamb side of the hinge.

Comment: Looks like either your door is warped, or your door stop is.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the First step would be to tighten the screws, if that did not work, replace them with a 1/4 inch longer screws.

If that did not work, do not bend the hinges. Stupid idea. Clearly your top hinge is not holding the door in place and longer screws should fix that.

Comment: The top hinge is not the issue. If it were the door would be tight at the top and not the bottom.  It is the bottom hinge that needs to be drawn tighter to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had an issue with an out of square door frame (jambs not parallel) that caused a similar issue. It was installed that way. All things considered, I used a plane to shave off some of the edge of the door. Granted, it was a power plane, but even with a hand plane, it would have been easier than pulling the hallway trim (painted), bathroom side trim and ceramic tile, and persuading the offending jamb with a 2x4 and 5-lb sledge.

Comment: thanks - I have been thinking about planing as well , I might give it a try.  been having knee issues so I have put this task in the sideline for now.

Answer (score -2):

If your hinge screws aren't catching then break off some pieces of toothpicks and stick them in there. It may take a few. Try to break them the exact length of the screw hole, shove them in the hole followed by your screw. That should keep it tight.

If your hinge plates are tight against the door and wall then use a knucklebender to true it up: [https://www.amazon.com/Fastcap-Knuckle-Bender/dp/B0082DDNHO/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0082DDNHO)

doors can sag for various reasons particularly in older houses. I would be curious as to exactly why its sagging in the first place if that is indeed the issue. Maybe its nothing or maybe its a foundation issue?

Comment: The door does not appear to be sagging.  The bottom hinge need tightened to the frame.  A tiny amount like 1/16 of and inch can cure a gap issue that is too big or too small.  The Knuckle bender could work if longer screws don't.

Comment: hello - the bathroom door is close to the door entrance.  but  the main entrance door is fine (no sagging)  so I think it may not be the foundation issue.